# Finding unused SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there any way to find unused SQL Server 2005 databases ?

I'm in the process of upgrading and migrating my server into SQL Server 2008 x64 in new server instance from 2005 32 bit.

Comment: Take them offline - see who complains? Depending on what this server is, this may be a valid approach (i.e., possible for development servers, not so realistic for live).

Comment: But for live servers you get faster feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: if the `last_access` column is null then no reads or writes have occurred:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT database_id, dt, op 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    UNPIVOT (dt for op in (last_user_lookup, last_user_scan, last_user_seek, last_user_update)) b)
SELECT d.name DB, MAX(c.dt) last_access, MAX(i.sqlserver_start_time) sqlserver_start_time, GETUTCDATE() captured
FROM sys.databases d 
LEFT JOIN cte c ON d.database_id=c.database_id
CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info i
WHERE d.database_id>4
GROUP BY d.name 
ORDER BY d.name;
```

Comment: wow, that's great, I've never heard about this feature. Thanks @Francesco

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer - heard of what feature? sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats is already in my answer. It basically copies the concept of getting the max from last_user_lookup, last_user_scan, last_user_seek, last_user_update (though using unpivot is less efficient than my way that calculates the per row max as it goes) and adds a couple of extra columns not asked for in the question

Answer (score 4):

Not a fool proof way. A couple of things that spring to mind are.

See which databases have few pages in the buffer pool

```
select db.name, COUNT(*) As page_count
from sys.databases db LEFT JOIN sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors bd ON db.database_id = bd.database_id
group by db.database_id, db.name
order by page_count
```

Or look at the index usage stats for each database

```
SELECT db.name, 
(SELECT MAX(T) AS last_access FROM (SELECT MAX(last_user_lookup) AS T UNION ALL SELECT MAX(last_user_seek) UNION ALL SELECT MAX(last_user_scan) UNION ALL SELECT MAX(last_user_update)) d) last_access
FROM sys.databases db 
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats iu ON db.database_id = iu.database_id
GROUP BY db.database_id, db.name
ORDER BY last_access
```

You could also use logon triggers to log access ongoing for a certain period just to be sure that nothing seems to be accessing "dead" databases before switching them offline.

Answer (score 3):

With SQL Server 2005, you can use the dynamic management view sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats. The name says "index" but that's a little misleading - every table has an entry in here, even if it doesn't have any indexes. Here's a useful query from SQL Magazine:

```
SELECT  
  t.name AS 'Table',  
  SUM(i.user_seeks + i.user_scans + i.user_lookups)  
    AS 'Total accesses', 
  SUM(i.user_seeks) AS 'Seeks', 
  SUM(i.user_scans) AS 'Scans', 
  SUM(i.user_lookups) AS 'Lookups' 
FROM  
  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats i RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
    sys.tables t ON (t.object_id = i.object_id) 
GROUP BY  
  i.object_id,  
  t.name ORDER BY [Total accesses] DESC
```

Here's the original article:

http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/53878/sql_server_53878.html

Keep in mind that these usage statistics reset when SQL Server restarts.

Comment: Shouldn't you join into sys.databases instead of tables? I.e. SELECT  
  t.name AS 'Table',  
  SUM(i.user_seeks + i.user_scans + i.user_lookups)  
    AS 'Total accesses', 
  SUM(i.user_seeks) AS 'Seeks', 
  SUM(i.user_scans) AS 'Scans', 
  SUM(i.user_lookups) AS 'Lookups' 
FROM  
  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats i RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
    sys.databases t ON (t.database_id = i.database_id) 
GROUP BY  
  i.database_id,  
  t.name ORDER BY [Total accesses] DESC

Answer (score 1):

Combine any of these methods to find out which databases are *still* in use

- listing connections

  ```
  select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
  ```
- listing active processes

  ```
  select * from sys.sysprocesses
  ```
- listing execution statistics

  ```
  select DB_NAME(database_id),  
      max(isnull(isnull(last_user_scan, last_user_update), 
          isnull(last_user_seek, last_system_scan))) 
  from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
  group by DB_NAME(database_id)
  ```
- storing LOGON timestamps

create a [LOGON TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) and insert the [EVENTDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx) contents into a table for later querying, examples [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic271709-294-1.aspx), [here](http://www.vandeputte.org/2006/11/sql-server-logon-triggers-part-2.html)